# What meaning is there behind the World Martial Arts Tournament logo?

Tags: dragon-ball, japanese-language, dragon-ball-gt

Everybody knows the [World Martial Arts Tournament](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/World_Martial_Arts_Tournament), which has a logo that you can see in flags, on the wall, in the arena, and at a lot of places during the tournament.

**But what does the logo exactly mean?** What language is that?

Here is the logo:

[image: World Martial Arts Tournament]

---

I found some references here:

- http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/World_Martial_Arts_Tournament
- http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_symbols
- http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Mutaito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Budou (武道) is a Japanese term describing Japanese martial arts. Budou consists of the kanji "[bu](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A6)" (武, ぶ), meaning "war" or "martial," and [dou](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%81%93) (道, どう), meaning "path" or "way."

The tournament is called the 天下一武道会, "Tenkaichi Budoukai," which can literally mean: "(Best) Martial Arts on Earth (Under the Sky) Tournament."

Comment: source ? reference ?

Comment: You can find the definition in a Japanese dictionary, if you're so inclined.

Comment: well, I just want to know if you got it from a website, so I can go and take a look for others symbols.